# InverseFunction and Plot them

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, interpolation, inverse-function

I'm trying plot an inverse function

```
InverseFunction[2 A ArcTanh[(# A)/Sqrt[-1 + #^2 B]] + A Log[1 + #^2 (A^2 - B)] - 2 Log[# B + Sqrt[-1 + #^2 B]] &][x]

Plot[Abs[%] /. {A -> 0.2, B -> 0.3}, {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

But I can't get any result??!!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 7):

We can draw `y=f[x]` by

```
ParametricPlot[{x, f[x]}, {x, 0, 2}]
```

and draw its inverse `x=f[y]` by

```
ParametricPlot[{f[y], y}, {y, 0, 2}]
```

```
f[x_] := 2 A ArcTanh[(# A)/Sqrt[-1 + #^2 B]] + 
       A Log[1 + #^2 (A^2 - B)] - 2 Log[# B + Sqrt[-1 + #^2 B]] &[
     x] /. {A -> 0.2, B -> 0.3} // Abs;
ParametricPlot[{{x, f[x]}, {f[x], x}}, {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

We can also use `ContourPlot`

```
f[x_] := 2 A ArcTanh[(# A)/Sqrt[-1 + #^2 B]] + 
       A Log[1 + #^2 (A^2 - B)] - 2 Log[# B + Sqrt[-1 + #^2 B]] &[
     x] /. {A -> 0.2, B -> 0.3} // Abs;
ContourPlot[{y == f[x], x == f[y]}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]
```

Comment: You just plot f(x) but as you see I used InverseFunction[f(x)] it means I want to plot f^-1(x)

Comment: @ArminSharafi Here we draw `y=f[x]` and `x=f^-1[y]` at the same picture.