# Plotting Inverse Function - more complicated

Tags: plotting, functions, inverse

I would like to plot the inverse of $f$ using the same method that was suggested to me in [my previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/237350/27951):

f[x_] := [(2 μ ArcTanh[(# μ)/Sqrt[-α + #^2 ν]] + μ Log[α + #^2 (μ^2 - ν)] - 2 Sqrt[ν]Log[# ν + Sqrt[ν] Sqrt[-α + #^2 ν]])/( 2 μ^2 - 2 ν)] &[x] /. {μ -> 0.2, α -> 0.3, ν -> 0.5} // Abs;

ParametricPlot[{{x, f[x]}, {f[x], x}}, {x, 0, 2}]

But it's not working?

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: You don't seem to be asking a question here.  (And the badly formatted code is hard to decipher.)

Comment: You can’t use square brackets `[...]` to group calculations in Mathematica; you should use parentheses instead `(...)`. Also, what is your question specifically?

Comment: `ParametricPlot[{x, f[x]}, {x, 0, 2}]` seems like the right way.

Comment: `f[x_] := (2 μ ArcTanh[(# μ)/Sqrt[-α + #^2 ν]] + μ Log[α + #^2 (μ^2 - ν)] -2 Sqrt[ν] Log[# ν +Sqrt[ν] Sqrt[-α + #^2 ν]])/(2 μ^2 -2 ν) &[x] /. {μ -> 0.2, α -> 0.3, ν -> 0.5} // Abs; ParametricPlot[{{x, f[x]}, {f[x], x}}, {x, 0, 2}]`